# Displaying text vertically (Japanies characters with ruby annotation) in android app

Tags: android, textview, text-styling

In my android app, I want to display japanies characters verticlaly with ruby annotations. The text and asnnotation comes dynamically from a service. Prestty much something like this ([https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-ruby-data/vertical.png][1]). At first glance this seems to be a solved problem. But surprisingly I dont see much material on Internet about this scenario. I am skiming through various topics in android but no luck. Can any one share some resource that I can look into.

I already came across the /n approach, Honestly felt we can solve this little better (not sure though)

Answer (score 0):

In your, Textview use this line

android:rotation="90"

like I set the text verticle.

Comment: Thanks @Pawan for responding. Unless I miss something, I think it will just rotate the text box, still the text orientation wont change. Could you please look at the image I shared in the question.